# Почему "негр" неполиткорректно?

Tags: стилистика, этикет

В процессе составления вопроса об "арапах" подумала: а почему, собственно, слово "негр" считается неполиткорректным? Что в этом оскорбительного для расы? Ведь "negro" — по-латыни "черный". Чем это хуже "чернокожего"? Ведь ни один европеоид не посчитает оскорблением, если его назовут "белокожим".

[image]

Comment: не могли бы вы привести источник своего ощущения "неполиткорректности"? Я вот как-то не чувствую, что "негр" неполиткорректно. У нас в Иркутске погоду по телевизору предсказывает именно негр. И все жители города это видят и знают. И никого это не раздражает (самого негра - Франсуа - в том числе).

Comment: Все вопросы в Америку. Там слово "негр" считается чуть ли не оскорблением, а говорят "афроамериканец"

Comment: В вопросе не указано, *где* возникает проблема политкорректности. Мы живём в России. По умолчанию я предположил, что идёт речь о политкорректности русского общества. Причём тут Америка? Почему вопросы - туда?..

Уточняю *свой* вопрос: откуда информация (или хотя бы ощущение), что **в России** слово "негр" - неполиткорректно? У меня такого ощущения нет. Информации - тоже.

Comment: Слово, на мой взгляд, не является оскорблением - Вы спокойно можете употреблять его в обыденной речи, находясь в Российской Федерации или в любых других странах бывшего СССР. В Америке, я думаю, Вы так делать не станете: Вас могут избить за такие слова.

Comment: >Ведь "negro" — по-латыни "черный"

Это не латынь, а испанский и португальский.

На латинском языке *чёрный* - niger, *чёрная* - nigra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Насколько я знаю, неполиткорректным это слово у нас стало исключительно с распространением в нашей речи всяческих англицизмов, последние где-то лет двадцать-тридцать. До этого слово считалось вполне себе приличным. Почему оно оскорбительно в США - это совсем другой вопрос.

Происхождение слова из латыни не имеет большого значения при определении его стилистической окраски. Слова *жид* и *еврей* тоже имеют разное употребление, хотя означают одно и то же.

Comment: Откуда информация, что слово "негр" стало неполиткорректным **у нас**? Можете привести источник?

Comment: Не понимаю какой источник Вы имеете в виду. Есть определенные нормы общения, любое слово имеет свою стилистическую окраску. Для разных ситуаций, для разной аудитории эти нормы различны. В выпусках новостей на центральных телеканалах Вы часто слышите слово "негр"?

Comment: ну, отчего же. Центральное телевидение вполне можно считать источником. Даже при такой "отрицательной" информации (отсутствие слова). 

Я вообще очень редко смотрю новости, так что для меня телевизор не аргумент. Но вполне аргумент - сообщение другого участника о телевизионной лексике (принимаю на веру).

------------

Правда, тут не хватает второй половины: информации о том, что слово *негр* **когда-то** часто звучало на ЦТ, а потом перестало использоваться. Так было?

Answer (score 8):

Дамы и Кавалеры!
Вам не кажется, что вы не стой стороны за эту неполиткорректность взялись?
Само по себе слово не может быть ни корректным, ни некорректным. Его делает таковым наша мораль, что уже выводит проблему за рамки лингвистики. 
Мораль же всегда ситуационна, нет единых правил, что бы там не утверждали апологеты христианской или "общечеловеческой" морали.

Со словами, используемыми для обозначения национальной или расовой принадлежности, религии, вообще все запущено донельзя. 
Почему-то французы не обижаются на "лягушатников", а вот у нас даже "хохол" считается обидным. В отношении же слова "негр" и политкорректности вообще могу сказать только одно. Искусственное перенесение на русскую почву в общем-то вполне разумных начал американской действительности до добра не доводит. Это не "мерикосы" маразматики, маразматики те наши соотечественники, кто, мало что поняв в источнике, доводит до абсурда подобные нормы. Отдаленный перевод на русский английского "Negro" в его бытовом значении - "холоп". Отсюда и все англо-американские заморочки. Но у нас никогда не было расового рабства. Почему вдруг слово "негр" стало обидным в русском?

> Дело не в самом слове, а его применении.

Я бы уточнил. **В том, как к нему относится тот, к кому оно обращено**. Без этого применяй - не применяй... Ну как объяснить далекому от российских реалий англичанину, почему он ответит именно за козла? Тем более - чеху, для которого козел - символ благополучия? Зато motherfucker не понятно среднестатистическому русскому Ивану. Хотя одно - вполне себе контекстный перевод другого...

Answer (score 5):

Слово  негр  стало  неполиткорректным  в  связи  с  ростом  национального  самосознания   как  американских   негров  так  и   жителей  бывших   европейских  колоний.  Сама  терминология  расовых  именований - европейская.  Назвать  в  Европе  и  в  США  кого -то  белым - для  белых  не  оскорбительно.  А  в  Африке,  возможно,  оскорбительно.  Не  исключено,  что  у  них  для  белых  и  другие  клички  имеются.  В  России  негров  нет,  поэтому  и  нет  ощущения   оскорбительности.  У  нас  это  слово  вполне   нейтрально.  Да  и  не  известно,  часто,  как  кого  называть.  Дипломатов   всё-таки  учат  где,  кого  и  как  называть.  Политически  корректно.  Для  обычного  общества,  вместо  не  очень   понятного  слова - политкорректность,  лучше  подходят  слова:  образованность,  культурность,  воспитанность. Или  тактичность.  Все  из  старого  словарного  запаса.

Comment: Мне кажется, что образованность, культура и воспитанность - это более... фундаментальные понятия. А вот понятие "политкорректность" сейчас носит не самые приятный оттенок. Потому что из соображения "политкорректности" по отношению к гомосексуалистам, например, в некоторых штатах США запретили слова "мама" и "папа".  
Сейчас понятие "политкорректности" все больше становится синонимом слова "маразм".

Comment: Дело  не  в самом  слове,  а  его  применении.